# inventory summary Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Well after much messing about I have finally got a query that gives sales totals of all the products, and another that gives stock absorbed for all of the products, (images below).

I was looking at Allen Brown's stuff and I get it, but I was wondering If i could make a summary report covering all of the available stock for all of the products. there are 31 products in total and they all appear in the stock query and in the sales query.

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/810/87887.jpg

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/827/8787j.jpg

Any Ideas on the coding to use...

I guess it would be possible to do, but then I don't really know where to start

I really want to make a report which will summarise the stock of each of the products in the queries.

Instead of having a button for working the stock of one specific product, having a button that will work the stock for each of the products in the queries at the same time.

does this make sense?

Thanks

Sam
UPDATE

this is the query for finding stock

```
SELECT TblStock.ProductID, Sum(TblStock.StockLevel) AS Stock, TblProduct.Item
FROM TblStock INNER JOIN TblProduct ON TblStock.ProductID = TblProduct.ProductID
GROUP BY TblStock.ProductID, TblProduct.Item;
```

this is the query for finding quantity of sales

```
SELECT TblProduct.Item, Sum(TblTotalSale.Size) AS Quantity, TblProduct.ProductID
FROM TblProduct INNER JOIN TblTotalSale ON TblProduct.[ProductID] = TblTotalSale.[ProductID]
GROUP BY TblProduct.Item, TblProduct.ProductID;
```

TblStock looks like

```
StockID ProductID   StockLevel
89  32  200
90  33  72
91  34  72
92  1   528
93  3   528
94  5   528
95  9   528
96  7   528
97  18  80
98  30  72
99  31  204
```

Product Table looks like

```
ProductID   Item    Price   StockDelivery   PriceSmall  Large   Small
1   Carling £2.50   528 £1.40   2   1
3   Carlsburg   £2.70   528 £1.60   2   1
5   IPA £2.30   528 £1.20   2   1
7   StrongBow   £2.80   528 £1.65   2   1
9   RevJames    £2.45   528 £1.30   2   1
11  Becks   £2.90   72      1   
12  WKDBlue £2.80   72      1   
13  WKDRed  £2.80   72      1   
14  SmirnoffIce £2.80   72      1   
15  KoppaburgPear   £3.10   72      1   
16  KoppaburgSum    £3.10   72      1   
17  Bulmers £2.90   72      1   
18  Vodka   £1.60   80      1   
19  Gin £1.40   80      1   
20  Sherry  £1.40   80      1   
21  Sambuca £1.70   80      1   
22  Rum £1.60   80      1   
23  Port    £1.60   80      1   
24  Whiskey £1.60   80      1   
25  Baileys £1.60   80      1   
26  Jagermeister    £1.50   80      1   
27  Martini £1.60   80      1   
28  CokeCan £0.85   72      1   
29  Coke    £1.30   204 £0.30   2   1
30  LemonadeCan £0.85   72      1   
31  Lemonade    £1.30   204 £0.30   2   1
32  Squash  £0.25   200     1   
33  Tonic   £0.85   72      1   
34  RedBull £1.90   72      1   
35  Nuts    £0.60   70      1   
36  Crisps  £0.60   70      1
```

tbltotalSale looks like

```
TotalSalesID    ProductID   SalePrice   Day Time    Size
370 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  19:53:14    2
371 1   £1.40   05/02/2012  19:53:14    1
372 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  19:53:14    2
373 1   £1.40   05/02/2012  19:53:14    1
374 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
375 1   £1.40   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
376 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
377 1   £1.40   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
378 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
379 1   £2.50   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
380 1   £1.40   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
381 5   £2.30   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
382 5   £2.30   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
383 5   £1.20   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
384 7   £2.80   05/02/2012  20:25:12    2
385 7   £1.65   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
386 7   £1.65   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
387 9   £1.30   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
435 11  £2.90   05/02/2012  20:25:12    1
436 11  £2.90   05/02/2012  20:42:49    1
437 11  £2.90   05/02/2012  20:42:49    1
```

I can upload my database if that would be easyer.

have tried to use the following Query for what i want, but it returns 11 results for each product id and none that are correct....

```
SELECT QrySaleTot.Item, QrySaleTot.ProductID, [QryStockLevel].[Stock]-[QrySaleTot].[Quantity] AS StockOnHand
FROM QrySaleTot, QryStockLevel
GROUP BY QrySaleTot.Item, QrySaleTot.ProductID, [QryStockLevel].[Stock]-[QrySaleTot].[Quantity];
```

Thanks

Comment: You question is unclear to me. Do you wish to show the stock query and the sales query at the same time? If so, why not just add the two queries to the query design window and create a relationship with the relevant field?

Comment: I want to creat a query that will add the records in the two tables, or rather subtract the value in the table of sales from the value in the table of stock, where the ID is the same, 

eg I want the value of sale for id 1 to be taken from the value of Stock for ID 1, but I want the query to do this for all ID's so the result of the query will have 29 values in it

Comment: Your final example is missing a JOIN. You can create the join by dragging product id from one to the other. The final result does not have 29 items - is it your intention that all products, regardless of sales and stock levels should appear in your result? Have you looked at LEFT JOIN yet in your reading?

Comment: Thank you. the inner join fixed it :)

Yes, this was a query to creat a summary report for the manager to show him current stock.  all the products should be in it. they will all have stock in the tbl stock so no errors will occur, even if there are no sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join the two tables by id and just subtract.

```
SELECT Sales.ID, Stock.Level - Sales.Quantity 
FROM Sales 
INNER JOIN Stock
ON Sales.ID = Stock.ID
```

Updating is not so different. Play around with the query design window. You may wish to read:

[`Fundamental Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140011%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Intermediate Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa140015%28office.10%29.aspx)
[`Advanced Microsoft Jet SQL for Access 2000`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa139977%28office.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I am not using tables, just queries
I have this
SELECT QryStockLevel.ProductID, QryStockLevel.Item, QryStockLevel.Stock - QrySaleTot.Quantity
FROM QrySaleTot, QryStockLevel
INNER JOIN QryStockLevel ON QrySaleTot.ProductID = QryStockLevel.ProductID;

But it is not working, syntax error on inner join...

Any Further Ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Your queries must be based on tables, so yes, you are using tables. Please post the SQL of the queries and sample data when you are requesting a detailed response.

Comment: Hey, I updated the question to include some of the data from the relevant tables. I also included the SQL for the two queries and my guess work for the new one

Thanks Sam

Answer (score 1):

You included this query in the update to your question:

```
SELECT
    QrySaleTot.Item,
    QrySaleTot.ProductID,
    [QryStockLevel].[Stock]-[QrySaleTot].[Quantity] AS StockOnHand
FROM QrySaleTot, QryStockLevel
GROUP BY
    QrySaleTot.Item,
    QrySaleTot.ProductID,
    [QryStockLevel].[Stock]-[QrySaleTot].[Quantity];
```

The first problem is you don't have a join condition ... so each row from QrySaleTot will be matched up with every row from QryStockLevel.  That will produce what is called a Cartesian product, or [cross join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).  Revise it to use a join on a field the 2 queries have in common.

The GROUP BY doesn't seem useful here because you're not computing any aggregate values.

Finally, Item is a reserved word.  If you must keep that field name, bracket it everywhere you reference it in your queries like this: `QrySaleTot.[Item]`

Comment: Thank you. the inner join fixed it :)